# Multiple urls Tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey

For the first time in my live i make a Tampermonkey script.

I want add multiple url's to a page: https://voertuig.net/zoek/merk/volkswagen/datum-tenaamstelling/30-05-2018?pagina=3

But i don't know how to get all different licenseplates for the custom urls. He now take the first licenseplate div.

url must be: https://finnik.nl/kenteken/XX-XX-XX/gratis

[image: As you can see, all urls have the same licenseplate]

As you can see, all urls have the same licenseplate

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://voertuig.net/zoek/merk/volkswagen/datum-tenaamstelling/30-05-2018?pagina=3
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=voertuig.net
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  "use strict"

  // Your code here...
var adduserinfo = $("div.voertuig > a");
var Username = $("div.kenteken");
var words = Username.html().split(' ');

adduserinfo.each (function () {

        var jThis = $(this);
        jThis.parent ().append ('<a href="https://finnik.nl/kenteken/' + words + '/gratis#historie">Finnik ' + words + ' </a>');

    } );
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

Note that you need to modify the `//@match` line or it will only work for the given page (i.e. page 3 -- just end the line with a `*` at the point where the match can be wild-carded.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         voertuig.net SO EXAMPLE
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://voertuig.net/zoek/merk/volkswagen/datum-tenaamstelling/30-05-2018?pagina=3
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    //Look closely - this is not jQuery
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

    $('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', init_css() );
    $$('.voertuig').forEach((div) => {
        const lp = div.getAttribute('data-kentekenplaat');
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<a target='_blank' class='finTagA' href='https://finnik.nl/kenteken/${lp}/gratis#historie'>Finnik ${lp}</a>`);
    });

})();
function init_css(){
    return `
    <style id="jdInitCss">
        .finTagA{width:100%;padding:5px;display:flex;justify-content:center;background:white;border-top:1px solid #ccccccCC;}
        .finTagA:hover{color:blue;}
    </style>
    `;
}
```