# Add html to the page, not accessible by script of page

Tags: tampermonkey

I am use tampermonkey extension.

I want to add html to page from tampermonkey script - i am have not problems with that.
I do it like this

```
        GM_addElement(window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], 'div', {
            textContent:'success',
            class: 'buba'
        });
```

But this code will added to the page, and will be accessible from script of this page.
Is there any sandbox for this? I need to add html, to a page, but the page doesn't have access to that html, and can't detect me

Comment: Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting it as the "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer). Doing that will acknowledge the answer and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1):

HTML added to a page by Tampermonkey is added to the DOM alongside the rest of the HTML. Any HTML injected by Tampermonkey is not segregated in any way. For example, if your Tampermonkey script adds an element with a certain class, any pre-existing JavaScript that affects all elements with that class will also affect the Tampermonkey-injected element with that same class.

There are also other methods for injecting elements. See this post:

[Multiple urls Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340944/multiple-urls-tampermonkey/72538298#72538298)